# Laravel 4 - how to use a unique validation rule / unique columns with soft deletes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Assume, you are trying to create a new user, with a User model ( using soft deletes ) having a unique rule for it's email address, but there exists a trashed user within the database.

When trying to validate the new user's data, you will get a validation error, because of the existing email.

I made some kind of extra validation within my Controllers, but wouldn't it be nice to have it all within the Model?

Would you suggest creating a custom validation rule?

As I haven't found a clean solution now, I am interessted in how others solved this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with your business logic rather than a technical problem.

The purpose of a soft delete is to allow for the possibility that the soft-deleted record may be restored in the future. However, if your application needs uniqueness of email (which is completely normal), you wouldn't want to both create a new user with that email address and be able to restore the old one as this would contravene the uniqueness requirement.

So if there is a soft deleted record with the email address for which you are adding as a new record, you should consider instead restoring the original record and applying the new information to it as an update, rather than trying to circumvent the uniqueness check to create a new record.

Comment: Did you just post this here: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=45610#p45610 sneaky.

Comment: Not intended to be sneaky. But as the questioner is asking in both places, kinda needing answering in both ;)

Comment: Oh no, no. Totally all for that :]

Comment: Actually I implemented the soft delete feature in order to give admin users the possibility to restore deleted users, if deleted accidently. I didn't think of restoring the user automatically in case of a request to create it with same nick / email.

What's your proposal of handling the restoring when nickname as welll as email address is unique, and the user that should be created has a nickname same to deleted user A, but email same to deleted user B ( assuming both have to be unique )?

Comment: What about if you have a business logic like this: You are just preserving the deleted record for tracking purposes and not historical purposes. Example of this are sets of configurations, some of it might be upgraded. And you just want to preserve the old one. Does soft-delete is applicable for that or there is another way?

Comment: @lukaserat That just about seems OK, as you're explicitly recognising that you won't have uniqueness in your design. Though better I feel would be to either move the deprecated settings to a table dedicated to that purpose, or have a log file that record the changes (with timestamp and user id maybe) rather preserving the old settings)

Answer (score 18):

You can validate passing extra conditions:

```
'unique:users,deleted_at,NULL'
```

Answer (score 14):

This is the best approach

```
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
```

It give you this query

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ? and `deleted_at` is null
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps to show what the actual query will be for the unique rules, otherwise they can be hard to understand.

Comment: When I'm trying to update a model it gives me an error because this email already exists, and yes, it's true it exists, but it belongs to the same instance I'm trying to update!

Answer (score 7):

Laravel offers "**[Additional Where Clauses](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique)**".

My url validation rule (from the **update** model method) looks like this:

```
$rules['url'] = 'required|unique:pages,url,'.$page->id.',id,deleted_at,NULL';
```

This means that the url must be unique, must ignore the current page and ignore the pages where `deleted_at` id not `NULL`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Somehow I managed to ignore the possibility of adding multiple unique rule dependencies for quite a long time. Nevertheless I am not sure if it would be better to change my business logic ( as I did ) as described in the answer of @petercoles

Also Gabriel Koerich wrote an answer similar to yours

Comment: Yeah! I agree with @petercoles myself. It's better to have a good business logic.
But sometimes you just need to have a workaround...
I'm glad it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 6.2+ you can use

```
'email' => ['required', Rule::unique('users')->whereNull('deleted_at')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Eloquent model should have the `$softDeletes` property set. If so, then when you perform a WHERE check, like `User::where('username', 'jimbob')`, Eloquent will automatically add in the query `WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`... which excludes soft deleted items.

Comment: The problem is, that I am using the "unique" validation rule,  and the Validator class does not use the Model class when making the check, thus not adding the deleted at automatically. Would you suggest not using the Validator, but adding the validation to a separate model method?

Comment: Looking at the API, it seems that the `DatabasePresenceVerifier` class uses query builder to query the tables for existence. With that said, it does not take into consideration of soft deletes. As I was going to mention before @kuroi did, I was going to say why not check the account validity first then restore the account if it existed prior to the registration...