# Laravel Soft Delete Unique column name

Tags: php, laravel, unique, soft-delete

Suppose I have category table and I have used soft delete on it. Now first time I have added one category "Test" after that I have delete this category so it will update my `deleted_at` column from the database.

Now when again I am trying to add category with name "Test" it is saying me that this name has been taken. I have tried with rules which are posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458681/laravel-4-how-to-use-a-unique-validation-rule-unique-columns-with-soft-delet).

But it is not working. I have used trait in my model. Below is my model code.

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator as Validator;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Category extends \Eloquent {

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * Guarded fields which are not mass fillable
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = array('id');

    /**
     * Name of the table used
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'travel_categories';

    /**
     * Validating input.
     *
     * @param array $input
     * @return mixed (boolean | array)
     */
    public static function validate($input, $id = null) {
        $rules = array(
            'name' => array('required','min:2','max:100','regex:/[a-zA-z ]/','unique:travel_categories,name,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL'),
            'description' => 'Required|Min:2',
            'image' => 'image'
        );
        if ($id) {
            $rules['name'] = 'Required|Between:3,64|Unique:travel_categories,name,'.$id;
        }

        $validation = Validator::make($input,$rules);

        return ($validation->passes())?true : $validation->messages();
    }
}
```

Comment: According to my understanding laravel use deleted_at column for soft delete, but database (mysql) doesn't know that, all it understand it's datetime column, so when you make a column unique database follow the rules, keep it unique...
and i think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458681/laravel-4-how-to-use-a-unique-validation-rule-unique-columns-with-soft-delet?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Did you understand the soft deleting purpose? It will only flag the data to be inactive. It will be there though.

So, if you define the values of that column must be unique, it is right you could not create other one alike.

- If it needs to be unique, so you should `restore` and `update` the data.
- If it can have many ones, so you should remove the unique key applied on it (and call it by relationship for instance).

Look at: [Laravel Eloquent Soft Deleting](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Answer (score 1):

First: I don't understand a couple of things. Are you trying to validate for create and update? Then why do you allow name to be of length 2 till 100 for creation, and only 3 till 64 for after updates?

Second: I recommend dropping this:

```
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

I don't see the goal of that.

Third, and I'm getting to the point here, what are you trying to do? I guess, what you are trying to do with this filter `'unique:travel_categories,name,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL'` is to check the uniqueness of the `name` among the active categories. In that case, that should work.

Comment: I have used validation rules here. what I want is when I am creating or updating new record then it will apply the validations rules aginst the value entered by user. Rules are mentioned in   `validate` method. Now when I am trying to create or update new category then it should check for the uniqueness of `category name`   which has`deleted_at = null` in database.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, a unique index on `[category, deleted_at]` will not work because when `deleted_at` is null, many SQL RDBMS will allow multiple records to be inserted despite a unique index existing.

In case anyone is interested I have now created a Laravel extension to handle the SQL unique-index constraints correctly: https://packagist.org/packages/tranzakt/laravel-softdeletesunique

If anyone tries this, please give feedback on Github, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is old, but I had a similar issue and I stumbled upon this. I wanted to mention how I fixed it for anyone, who is reading it in the future. The problem I had was that Laravel did not allow me to insert a value in a unique column when there was an old record with the same value, but was deleted using soft_delete.

To summarize, the goal is to ignore old soft deleted records for a unique column when inserting a new record. The solution I found is in the migration for the table. For example, let us assume we have these columns:

- category - unique
- deleted_at - keeps tracks of the deleted rows

Both should be specified as unique in the migration like so:

```
 Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string("category");
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->unique(["category", "deleted_at"]);
    });
```

Side note: If you already have the table like I did, you need to change the migration and create the table again (obviously the data will be lost):

- Remove the table
- Change the migration
- Remove the record about it from the migrations table
- run "php artisan migrate" to create the table again

Comment: Sorry to say, but that won´t work. Non deleted rows will have null in 'deleted_at' column, and null values don´t trigger the 'unique' constraint. That unique constraint only guarantees that you won´t have two categorys deleted at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding. I do expect that rows with `"deleted_at" = null` will not "trigger the unique constraint". If `"deleted_at" = null`, then we have an active row, meaning it was inserted, but has not been soft-deleted. Thus, it will be disregarded and the unique check will use only the value in the "category" column, which is the main unique column in my example above. What this setup did for me was, it allowed the unique check to work as usual, but ignore soft-deleted rows.

Comment: Just to confirm that the solution works perfectly.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Comment: no, sergio0983 is correct, entire unique index is not considered if any value is null. if you see the sqlfiddle here you will note that it is possible to create non unique table rows with this solution http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1516b1/1

Comment: Hi maaarghk. Thanks for the feedback, but I could not open your example. Perhaps you and sergio0983 are talking about a case that is slightly different than what I was trying to achieve. Feel free to adapt my example to your needs.

Comment: the solution works for me is to make the unique field nullable, so that before I delete the record, i'll just null it, save its value somewhere else (i usually have json field, and serve it as changes/delete log), then make the field NULL, in my case, `email` for unique email address constraint. The reason i prefer this is, I suspect making `deleted_at` and `email` field on same unique constraint is it could create massive indexing issues, specially for huge table with seldom deletes. I would rather solve it on the application level, than to enlarge my index just for rectifying this.