# Unique phone number checks with ignoring soft delete record - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add validations on my customers table. I am trying to ignore soft delete record and check uniqueness on phone number of active record.

```
$validation = Validator::make($data, [
            'phone_number' => 'required|unique:customers,deleted_at,NULL',
            'location_coordinates' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'location' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);
```

The field name is phone_number.

Its not working. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374995/check-if-name-is-unique-among-non-deleted-items-with-laravel-validation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if name is unique among non-deleted items with laravel validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374995/check-if-name-is-unique-among-non-deleted-items-with-laravel-validation)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458681/laravel-4-how-to-use-a-unique-validation-rule-unique-columns-with-soft-delet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by using the Rule.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule; 


'phone_number' => ['required', Rule::unique('customers', '<column for phone number>')->whereNull('deleted_at')],
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem in your code is you miss the filed name:

```
'phone_number' => 'required|unique:customers,deleted_at,NULL' ...
```

while it should be:

```
'phone_number' => 'required|unique:customers,phone_number,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
```

you can make unique constraint as simple as possible using a clouser:

```
'phone_number' => Rule::unique('customers','phone_number')->ignore($currentRecord->id)->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('deleted_at','=', null);
});
```

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique